# Cryptographically secure token generation in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

Is the following a cryptographically secure way to generate a random token? Does it have any of the predictability risks that are theoretically associated with using a GUID as a token?

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
            using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
                rng.GetBytes(bytes);
            }

            string hexToken = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine(hexToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is there to say about it?

The code generates 32 random bytes, fed by a good Cryptographically Secure Random Number Generator, seeded by the operating system. Then it converts to just lowercase hexadecimals.

There is only a very small chance that a `CryptographicException` is thrown by the random number generator, but if it happens it is currently not caught.